# Error installing glib

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning, gcc4.7

I am trying to install the glib-2.38.0 and upon executing the MAKE file and getting the following error:

```
make[5]: Leaving directory `/root/glib-2.38.0/glib/update-pcre'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/glib-2.38.0/glib/update-pcre'
Making install in .
make[4]: Entering directory `/root/glib-2.38.0/glib'
  CCLD     libglib-2.0.la
libtool: link: `glib_probes.lo' is not a valid libtool object
make[4]: *** [libglib-2.0.la] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/glib-2.38.0/glib'
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/glib-2.38.0/glib'
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/glib-2.38.0/glib'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/glib-2.38.0'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

How can I troubleshoot this?  How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2):

After hitting this same error on Solaris 10 01/13 and not needing dtrace support, I solved this in configure by adding --disable-dtrace.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and located your posting after
giving the error message to a search engine.  Alas, no one
had answered you, so I had no choice but to troubleshoot the
problem myself.

In my case, the problem was an old version of dtrace.  I updated
the package containing /usr/bin/dtrace (which, in my case, was
systemtap-sdt-devel) and then dtrace created a proper glib_probes.lo
file.

Having solved the problem for myself, it then became my duty to
tell you how I had done so, and answer your unanswered question.
This I have now done.